# YouTube Android Player API doesn't work on Amazon Fire TV

Tags: android, youtube, amazon-fire-tv

I need to implement playing Youtube Videos in Amazon Fine TV.
I desided to use https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/.
My activity is:

```
package com.ticketmaster.amazon.activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;
import com.ticketmaster.amazon.R;
import com.ticketmaster.api.helper.PropertiesHelper;

/**
 * Created by Georgii on 4/26/2016.
 */
public class PlaybackYoutubeActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements  YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
    private static final int RECOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
    public static final String YOUTUBE_KEY = "-----MYKEY----------";
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube);

        youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        PropertiesHelper.loadProperties(this);
        youTubeView.initialize(YOUTUBE_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo("fhWaJi1Hsfo"); // Plays https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhWaJi1Hsfo
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String errMsg = getString(R.string.video_error_unknown_error);
            Toast.makeText(this, errMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(YOUTUBE_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return youTubeView;
    }
}
```

**activity_youtube.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout mlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".activity.PlaybackYoutubeActivity">

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
  android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run the dialog epeares and clicking button "GET YOUTUBE BUTTON" doen't get any result. The value **YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason** in the callback **onInitializationFailure** is **SERVICE_MISSING**. Youtube App is installed in Amazon Fire TV.

Does anyone know how to run Youtube Video in Amazon Fire TV?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you figure it out?

Comment: I also have same problem :(

Answer (score 3):

I've faced the same problem.

After some research I've found possible answer [here](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/11126/how-to-play-youtube-videos-in-fire-tv.html)

Levon@Amazon wrote, that Youtube Video Player API is a part of Google API, not Android API, so that's why not working.

Possible solutions may be:

- sideload Google Play Services
- display YouTube video in WebView

Hope this helps

Comment: on Android 11 emulator everything should be fine with Google Play Services and YouTube apps but it doesn't work, only works prior Android 11 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64631893/youtube-api-oninitializationfailure-service-missing-on-android-11-sdk-30